# Forecasting & plotting 10,000 paths of expected returns from VAR(p) model in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, vector-autoregression

I am working in R with a vector autoregression (VAR) model.

**The objective.** I want to simulate/forecast 10,000 sets of paths from a VAR(p) model of the expected returns of 3 assets, as part of a pet project of mine.

**The problem.** Using the vars package, I fit my VAR(p) model and use the function `predict` to forecast an expected return path with X% confidence bands for each asset.

However, for each asset, I can’t figure out how to forecast discrete/individual paths instead of just having a confidence bands.

**The question.** What is the best way to forecast an expected returns path, replicate that simulation say 10,000 times, and plot those paths?

Thanks in advance & happy to provide more details if this is too general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, for each asset, I can’t figure out how to forecast discrete/individual paths instead of just having a confidence bands.

If your fitted VAR model is `model`, then `predict(model)$fcst` returns a list with forecasts. More precisely, each element in the list corresponds to forecasts for each endogenous variable in the VAR model.
A typical element of the list is a matrix containing four columns: point forecasts, upper and lower bounds and half the width of the forecast interval. 
To extract point forecasts, you have to take the first column.
E.g. `predict(model)$fcst[[k]][,1]` will give the point forecasts for variable number `k`.